# using for loops in python for integration?

Tags: python, loops

I have a simple code that works for single values of n, but I need to set up a loop to calculate/plot for n=2,5,20. I'm new to python, can someone show me how to do this?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import scipy.integrate as integrate
from scipy.integrate import quad
import math as m
y = lambda t: 3*t
T = 4      #period
n=20
#n = np.array([2,5,20])
w = 2*np.pi*n/T

#Bn
def integrand(t):
    return y(t)*np.sin(n*w*t)
Bn= (2/T)*quad(integrand,-T/2,T/2)[0] 
#An
def integrand(t):
    return y(t)*np.cos(n*w*t)
An= (2/T)*quad(integrand,-T/2,T/2)[0]

#A0
def integrand(t):
    return y(t)
A0= (1/T)*quad(integrand,-T/2,T/2)[0]

print(Bn,An,A0)
y = lambda t: A0+An*np.cos(n*w*t)+Bn*np.sin(n*w*t)

#y = lambda t: ((-1)**(n+1))*Bn*np.sin(w*n*t)

t = np.linspace(-6, 6)    
plt.plot(t,y(t))
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. Please see: [ask], [tour], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a for loop and do something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import scipy.integrate as integrate
from scipy.integrate import quad
import math as m

y = lambda t: 3*t
T = 4      #period
n_list = np.array([2,5,20])

for n in n_list:
    w = 2*np.pi*n/T
    Bn = (2/T)*quad(lambda t: y(t)*np.sin(n*w*t), -T/2, T/2)[0] 
    An = (2/T)*quad(lambda t: y(t)*np.cos(n*w*t), -T/2, T/2)[0]
    A0 = (1/T)*quad(lambda t: y(t), -T/2, T/2)[0]

    print(Bn,An,A0)
    y = lambda t: A0+An*np.cos(n*w*t)+Bn*np.sin(n*w*t)

    #y = lambda t: ((-1)**(n+1))*Bn*np.sin(w*n*t)

    t = np.linspace(-6, 6)
    plt.plot(t,y(t))
    plt.show()
```